# Errors when bundling javascript files of different pages into one

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

It looks stupid question, I'm using webpack to build static website

I wanted to bundle my JavaScript files of different pages into one

but some elements that I selected by **JS** that existing in `home page` and not in `about page` **throwing error** when I go to `about page`.

> It's not effective just in console and I can ignore it

should I separate files ? if so is that possible to make webpack inject different pages with the proper JS file?

---

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Try to make min files using webpack , or u cn use rollup.js 
If possible please share code snippet.